# Android C++ Gesture Code

Tags: c++, android, mobile, gesture-recognition, gesture

Is it possible to get gesture code to work with Android and C++? If so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way by far would be to pass the information from your [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) and/or [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) to your native code via the JNI.  Exactly how you do this is up to you, but the basic principle is no different than that of any other communication between native and Java code.

If you are asking if you can acquire MotionEvents without going via the JNI, if it's even possible, it's far more hassle than it's worth.  You could (and probably should) use a tool like [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) to avoid the pain of writing JNI wrapper code manually.